# fit_generator() doesn't works in Spyder

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, kernel, spyder

I am trying to use fit_generator() on Spyder for training a Neural Network (which I want to train for sorting out digit's images) and I always have the same problem. When I call the function the first result that I have is this one:

[image]

and then:

[image]

Basically, I do not understand what happen this. I will attach the code's segment.

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)

batches     = gen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64) # batches.n = 37800
val_batches = gen.flow(X_val, y_val, batch_size=64) # val_batches.n = 4200


history=model.fit_generator(generator=batches, steps_per_epoch=batches.n, 
                              epochs=3,  validation_data=val_batches,
                              validation_steps=val_batches.n)
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you using Anaconda?

Comment: Yes, I am using Anaconda

Comment: How did you install Tensorflow?

Comment: I am using python 3.6 and I cannot remember how Tensorflow was installed. I think I used this command "conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow"

Comment: That's probably the issue. Please create a new conda environment and install tensorflow with `conda install tensorflow`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and spent a few days searching the net for solutions / reinstalling a couple of times / nearly throwing my laptop out / giving up and gathering hope again / finally finding a solution. Special thanks to this [GitHub post](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8581)

Here's the step-by-step solution to what I did. I'm using a MacBook and Anaconda for python / Spyder:

- Installed Anaconda (c1.9.6) and through it Python in the (base) environment *[EDIT: It's the Anaconda version 2018.12 that I installed. The navigator `Anaconda Navigator > About Anaconda Navigator` states its Anaconda Navigator 1.9.6]*
- Through the Anaconda Navigator, created a new (deeplearning) environment
- Again using the Navigator, I installed Keras, Tensorflow, Theano, Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib, Scikit-learn, Spyder-kernels in the new (deeplearning) environment (and various associated packages were automatically installed)
- Using Terminal, in my (base) environment, I downgraded my Python from 3.7 to 3.6.8 (`conda install python=3.6`) so it would work with Keras *[EDIT: This step may be redundant and not required]*
- Using Terminal, went into my (deeplearning) environment and installed nomkl (`conda install nomkl`) (it asked to downgrade some packages to which I said ok)
- Still in my (deeplearning) environment in my Terminal, I typed `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` to get my path + copied the pathname
- Opened Spyder through my (base) environment and navigated to `Preferences > Python Interpreter > Use the following interpreter` where I input my path
- Restarted Spyder, again in the (base) environment and started coding. *[EDIT: You may not need to restart Spyder. Rather just open a new console tab].*

It all worked like a beauty. I can finally get on with learning more of this exciting field!

Just FYI... The first error image you get is not really an error, it's a warning that essentially means that the speed will not be as fast as it can be. The second image is the annoying error that took away a few days of my life to research a solution!